# How can I find all of rows which are selected by CSS in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, select, find

I want to find which the rows are selected by CSS using Javascript. I hava some lines and the code from some reference in other threads. See at the down below :

```
...
var trs = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');

for (var i = 2; i < trs.length; i++)
...
```

For reference, this is what I've got from some other threads :

```
...
var totSelect = document.querySelectorAll("input[id$='inpt']:checked").length;
...
```

CSS
...
   table tbody .selected tr {
        background-color: #E74C3C;
   }

How to implement the code above as a references to get and find all of rows selected by CSS in Javascript?

Comment: what is it that you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to select the same elements using javascript which are selected by your CSS.

If that's correct, just use the same selector in your JS.

```
var totSelect = document.querySelectorAll(`table tbody .selected tr`);
```

This will return an array containing all the same elements which received the `background-color: #E74C3C;`